# bash script -> ps read nothing of a command launch within the script

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, ps

I'd like to understand why when I execute the following command in my terminal it works, but when I run through a script it doesn't

the command when I run it in my terminal

```
./tparente & ps --no-headers -C tparente -o rss,vsz >> "mem_results"
```

The mem_result file has the rss and vsz written in it.
The command when I run it through my terminal is slightly modified, it is written like this:

```
sh ~/Documents/tparente & ps --no-headers -C tparente -o rss,vsz >> "mem_results"
```

There's an echo command that write some text in mem_results before the aforementioned command, those works.
And if I remove the no header flag, it writes the header in the file but not the result.

I know the script is run, because it produce a file at the end.
This has been bugging me for a couple hours now.

Thank you
Alex.

Comment: please edit your question to show the contents of `mem_results` in both cases. (you might want to append `_cmdline` and `_script`. Also recall that `>>` is appending to an existing file. If you make a mistake, the bad version will always appear at the top of the file when you go to check it. You might want to switch to `> mem_results_cmdline` etc. Good luck.

Comment: Are you sure `tparente` is still running in that second case correctly? Does using `bash ~/Documents/tparente & ps --no-headers -C tparente -o rss,vsz >> "mem_results"` work correctly?

Comment: Either using bash or shell doesn't give the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found the answer.

After trying a couple of configuration of the command line: this one works:

```
./tparente & ps --no-headers -C tparente -o rss,vsz >> "mem_results"
```

The difference is subtle (there's no "sh")
This line is from the script; what I noticed is when I tried to run the script on it's and run a ps command in another terminal, the tparente process was is there. I don't know why, but my instinct told me to remove the sh and I did and it works.

If anyone has a proper explanation go ahead :)